# How to print out "st_blksize" of data in ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04, system-calls, stat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    struct stat file;
    int n;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./a.out <filename>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if ((n = stat(argv[1], &file)) == -1)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("Block size : %d\n", file.st_blksize);
}
```

Last line gives an error

format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__blksize_t’ [-Wformat=]

How to print out "st_blksize" of data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `st_blksize` is a `unsigned long` typedefed datatype, hence use

```
printf("Block size : %ld\n", file_st.blksize);
```